# heroku Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Tags: python, java, spring-boot, flask, heroku

Hello everyone I want to someone till me if what I 'am doing is correct or not
what I 'am trying to do is deploying spring boot in heroku and getting date from python (flask) framework which I 'am running it locally in my device, everything is woking fine locally in my device but when try to run spring boot in heroku I 'am getting this error
`at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/hi" host=java-be.herokuapp.com request_id=454eaa9f-b9e3-4c03-9e7d-4bf5b6c450a9 fwd="5.45.134.17" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http`

and this error shows in heroku logs:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException:
 I/O error on GET request for "http://192.168.43.142:5000/":
 Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception
 is java.net.ConnectException:
 Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

My spring boot code :

```
 @GetMapping("/")
    String home() throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            String url = "http://192.168.43.142:5000/"; // flask local host url
            String helloWorld= restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
            SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory rf =(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
            rf.setReadTimeout(1000);
            rf.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            return helloWorld;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

And here's my flask code :

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "hello world"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        from waitress import serve
        serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
    except:
        print("unexpected error")
```

Also when I run heroku server locally it's working fine as well.

Comment: first check spring boot app working fine or not when you open app url its show white page error or not

Comment: pankaj it's telling me to check my logs , when I do I 'am getting the above error as you sow in the in the question

Comment: this means your spring boot app not deploy correctly please check heroku java version
and your system java version. By default heroku use java 1.8 you can change your spring java version 1.8 and deploy again and check

Comment: Actually I 'am using java1.8 pankaj

Comment: Is that your IP address and are you exposing it to be accessible from outside?

Comment: http://192.168.43.142:5000 this is your local server url may issue in your local server therefore it not connected and show you time out error forward your local server url using ngrok and replace your this http://192.168.43.142:5000 to ngrock url and try

Comment: pankaj do you have any article explain how I can do that.

Comment: Beppe yes it's my IP, I believe that I can access it if I 'am connected to same network.

Comment: https://ngrok.com/download
download file according to your system 
1) login ngrok website
2) get token from it 
3) run your local server
4) run ./ngrok authtoken <your token>
5) run ./ngrok http <your server port like 5000>
5th step provide you  a url use it and deploy your spring boot application and test again

Comment: welcome happy coding

Answer (score 0):

have you already configured the gunicorn package to deploy on heroku?

```
pip3 install flask gunicorn
```

and create the Procfile file and add:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```

Follow the link to How to Deploy: https://dev.to/techparida/how-to-deploy-a-flask-app-on-heroku-heb

Comment: Think you Lucas but I still didn't deploy flask in heroku I 'am running it locally, spring boot which I 'am running it in heroku .

Comment: can you pass your local git repository so I can make my own tests?

Comment: https://github.com/sabbagh99/springBoot-flask here's the repo contain flask and spring boot code